# Why does moment .add not return proper value?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I get an unexpected return when adding 1 month to the startOf month date.

```
const moment = require('moment');
var availableDate = "2023-05-07T00:00:00Z";
var monthID = moment(new Date(availableDate)).startOf('M').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

console.log ('Month: ', monthID);
monthID = moment(new Date(monthID)).add(1,'M').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

console.log('Month after the add: ', monthID);
```

Console log:
Month:  2023-05-01
Month after the add:  2023-05-30

I expected to get 2023-06-01

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a date-only ISO 8601 string like `2023-05-01` to the [Date() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#date_time_string_format), it is treated as UTC...

> When the time zone offset is absent, **date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time** and date-time forms are interpreted as local time

Depending on your timezone, it may result in a local representation earlier or later than you expect.

There's simply no need for all the parsing and formatting in your code...

```js
const availableDate = "2023-05-07T00:00:00Z";

const nextMonth = moment(availableDate).startOf("M").add(1, "M");

console.log("Month after the add:", nextMonth.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Of course, even [Moment.js doesn't recommend Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/). Consider using vanilla JS instead

```js
const availableDate = "2023-05-07T00:00:00Z";

const date = new Date(availableDate);
date.setDate(1);
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);

const formatted = `${
  date.getFullYear()
}-${
  (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0")
}-${
  date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0")
}`;

console.log("Month after the add:", formatted);
```